# How do I check if an IP address appears in a PCAP file?

Tags: wireshark, tshark

Is it possible to use tshark to check whether one or more ip addresses appear in a pcap file? I know that I can display all occurrences with `tshark -r infile -w outfile ip.addr==172.26.29.2 || ip.addr==172.26.31.21`, but is there an option to not display all (maybe only the first occurrence.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this, either taking these few steps:

1. Get the list of all source IP addresses:

   `tshark -r infile -Y "ip" -T fields -e ip.src > infile_ips.txt`
2. Append with the list of all destination IP addresses:

   `tshark -r infile -Y "ip" -T fields -e ip.dst >> infile_ips.txt`
3. Ensure all IPs are listed on separate lines, which they might not be in the case of tunneled IPs or for ICMP errors, then sort the list and eliminate duplicates:

   `cat infile_ips.txt | tr , '\n' | sort -u`

Or a bit more easily using this single step:

```
tshark -r infile -Y "ip" -T fields -e ip.addr | tr , '\n' | sort -u
```

Once you have the list of all unique IP addresses present in the capture file, you can search that list for whatever IP address you're interested in by using `grep` or by whatever other means you want.

Refer to the [`tshark` man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for more information regarding the options I used above.

Answer (score 0):

Another command that would work would be

```
tshark -q -z endpoints,ip -z endpoints,ipv6 -r infile
```

which would produce tables of IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, as well as, for each address, information about the amount of data transmitted from and to that address.